# how to remove a specific row in csv file based upon the duplicate using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file which has many rows looks like below.

```
20170718 014418.475476 [UE:142 CRNTI : 446] 

20170718 094937.865362 [UE:142 CRNTI : 546]
```

Above are the sample two rows of the csv file.

Now if we see the rows there is a string called [UE:142...] which repeats in the csv file.

Problem statement:

I want to remove the duplicate row which contains string [UE:< > more than once in that csv file i.e in the above rows the string [UE:142 repeated twice so the second one must get deleted, in this way there are many random strings like [UE:142 .

Can anyone please help me with python script for the above problem statement?

```
import csv
reader = open("test.csv", "r")
lines = reader.read().split(" ")
reader.close()

writer = open("test_1.csv", "w")
for line in set(lines):
    writer.write(line)
writer.close()
```

Comment: add your code/ attempt

Comment: import csv


reader = open("test.csv", "r")
lines = reader.read().split(" ")
reader.close()
 
writer = open("test_1.csv", "w")
for line in set(lines):
    writer.write(line)
writer.close()

Comment: I have used set but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
from csv import reader, writer as csv_writer

csv_path = '<your csv file path here>'

def remove_duplicate_ue (csv_path):
    found = False
    with open (csv_path, 'r') as csv_file:
        for line in reader (csv_file, delimiter = ' '):
            if 'UE:' not in line [-1]:
                yield line
            elif not found:
                yield line
                found = True

def write_csv (csv_path, rows, delimiter = ' '):
    with open (csv_path, 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv_writer (csv_file, delimiter = delimiter)
        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow (row)

write_csv (csv_path, tuple (remove_duplicate_ue (csv_path)))
```

Comment: I had run the code , but it doesn't remove the duplicate UE i.e UE:142 which is present twice ,  it is adding an empty row in between two rows.